# Dynamic width calculation of list elements

Tags: html, css, angular5

I need to implement some requirements:
Dynamically draw a list of `li` elements that can consist of text with different lengths. All elements that are to long to display in one line need to be replaced with `...`. I have achieved this with the following css:

```
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Typically this breadcrumb will have 1-5 elements. The first and last elements should always display the full text.

How can I calculate the max width of the `li` elements without including the width of last element? Something like:

```
calc((100% - width-last-element)/<li-el-qty>-1
```

I've tried the following:

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Regular breadcrumbs */

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2em;
  color: #333;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 8em;
}

li:after {
  content: '>';
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 0;
  width: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

li:nth-last-child(1) {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-overflow: clip;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul class="bread">
  <li>MERSEDES</li>
  <!--
  -->
  <li>Main transmission section1</li>
  <!--
  -->
  <li>Second Transmissio Section</li>
  <!--
  -->
  <li>Another to view</li>
  <!--
  -->
  <li>Final link the hierarchy</li>
  <!--
-->
  <li>Current section viewAAAAA</li>
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/nolik/pen/mKpWYm

I've also tried setting up dynamic width based on the number of elements like this:

```
/* three items */
li:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
li:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ li {
    max-width: 33.3333%;
}

/* four items */
li:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
li:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ li {
    max-width: 25%;
}
```

But neither has worked.

Comment: Is this the sort of result you are looking for? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KeZxMX

Comment: @HiddenHobbes perfect, thx! only one things => could u advice some way, make all elements collapse in equal proportion?

Comment: Please check the pen again, is this what you are after? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KeZxMX

Comment: little bit no, first version more near (just with increasing last element other elements collapsed not proportionally, u can see:  https://codepen.io/nolik/pen/mKpaGr  (u can see, that collapsed max-width of 1st element different with 3d, logically 1st element should be display fully). But anyway you has helped me so much!

Comment: Something like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKazox

Comment: Was the previous example what you were after @Nolik? If so I can write a full answer explaining the changes.

Comment: Thx so much @HidenHobbes. Please, post your answer, that i can resolve this question. actually it's big help with flex, now i try to customize your solution for cutting free spaces from the element that fully displayed and share this space with between others elements that we overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the result you are after by using `flexbox` and its `grow` and `shrink` properties.

The following modifications would be required:

- Add `display: flex;` to `ul`. This will make it a `flex` container
- Add `flex: 0 1 10%;` to `li`. This will tell the `li`s not to grow but to shrink with an initial length of `10%`
- Add the selector `li:first-child` with the rule `flex: 0 0 auto;`. This will ensure that the first `li` stays at its initial size and will not shrink
- Add the selector `li:last-child` with the rule `flex: 1 0 auto;`. This will ensure that the last`li` grows to fill the available space

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2em;
  color: #333;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex: 0 1 10%;
}

li:after {
  content: '>';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

li:nth-last-child(1) {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-overflow: clip;
  overflow: visible;
}

li:first-child {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

li:last-child {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="bread">
  <li>MERSEDES</li>
  <li>Main transmission section1</li>
  <li>Second Transmissio Section</li>
  <li>Another to view</li>
  <li>Final link the hierarchy</li>
  <li>Current section viewAAAAA</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `display: flex` on the parent element and then unset the `min-width` on the last child element. A quick example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.parent>div {
  min-width: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.parent>div:last-of-type {
  min-width: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <p>MERSEDES</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Final link the hierarchy</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Another to view to view</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Final link the hierarchy</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Another to view to view</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Final link the hierarchy</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <p>MERSEDES</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Final link the hierarchy</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Another to view to view</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Final link the hierarchy</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Another to view to view</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Final link the hierarchy</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Another to view to view</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <p>MERSEDES</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Final link the hierarchy</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Another to view to view</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Final link the hierarchy</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Another to view to view</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Final link the hierarchy</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Another to view to view</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Final link the hierarchy</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: excuse me @Vucko, i don't get how it should work without max-width in span class. (https://codepen.io/pen/)

Comment: @Nolik only the last child elements span doesn't have the `max-width` property so it can use all of its parents width.

Comment: thanks for reply, but problem that i need somehow dynamically configure max-width of not last child elements (all elements should try to fully expand except the case when it block show fully last element)

Comment: @Nolik now I get what you need. Will delete and repost if I find the answer.

Comment: sry, but seems your example work in other way:  https://codepen.io/nolik/pen/qKpLOg, see comment of >Hidden Hobbes, it's exactly what i need (only one thing that need to reach, it's equal proportion for all collapsed elements).